# Difference between length of rune slice and RuneCountInString?

Tags: go, utf-8, rune

We can get the number of runes in a string by getting the length of the rune slice converted from the string.

```
s := "世界"
runes := []rune(s)
fmt.Println(len(runes))
```

Or use the `RuneCountInString` function in `unicode/utf8` package.

```
fmt.Println(utf8.RuneCountInString(s))
```

What's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 6):

The difference is that the first one:

```
runes  := []rune(s)
length := len(runes)
```

has to step through `s` to build a slice of `rune`s and then ask that slice how long it is whereas [`utf8.RuneCountInString`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.10/src/unicode/utf8/utf8.go#L408) simply steps through `s` byte by byte incrementing a counter whenever it sees a sequence of contiguous bytes that make up a UTF-8 character.

The `[]rune(s)` version has to do more work than `utf8.RuneCountInString` does.

---

A cursory bit of wandering around the source suggests that `[]rune(someString)` is implemented by [`stringtoslicerune`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/release-branch.go1.10/src/runtime/string.go#L158) which actually does two iterations over the string: one two find out how many `rune`s are there and another to copy those `rune`s into a slice. I'm not certain about this as I'm not that familiar with the implementation details of Go.